# Metric (distance) for highly skewed data

Tags: skewness, metric

I am currently investigating some points in 4D in relation to some reference point (also in 4D). That is, I want to test how the distance to the reference point depends on some other variables.

Because I have not other theoretical reason to choose otherwise, I am just using the Euclidean distance ($d=\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^4 (x^*_i-x_i)^2}$, where $x^*$ is the reference point) to asses the distance between the points and the reference point.

However, the resulting distances are highly skewed, such that I have to take the log of the distances before performing any statistical tests. Taking the log of a distance seems somewhat weird to me.

Is there some metric that is better suited to this kind of data that can reduce the skew directly, such that I don't have to take the log afterwards?

Comment: If your distances don't seem fit for purpose, the implication to me is that you need to work in a different space. Log distance may seem practical but in principle zero distance should be a possible result, and in practice very small distances could be a nightmare on log scale.

Comment: @NickCox Yes, I thought about this, too. But currently, I have no idea what this space may look like. The distances are indeed very small, but these are results from a simulation, so I know they are not zero.